# How to get list<string> from list of list of list linq C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have the classes:

```
  public class Person
  {  
    public string Name{get;set;}   
    public bool IsMarried{get;set;}  
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
  }
  public class Child
  {
    public bool Greater5 { get; set; }
    public List<MyColor> ListColor { get; set; }
  }
  public class MyColor
  {
    public string History { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
  }
```

I want to obtain a list string (MyColor.Type which are not empty) for all persons where IsMarried=true and Children.Greater5 = true.
I can achieve this with:

```
  List<Person> list = personList.Where(l => l.IsMarried == true).ToList();
  List<Child> childList = list.SelectMany(c => c.Children).Where(test => test.Greater5 == true).ToList();
  List<string> wantedList= childList.SelectMany(test => test.ListColor.Where(c => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Type)).Select(t => t.Type)).ToList();
```

but I was wondering if it could be achieved using Linq to be more simpler?

Comment: _"but I was wondering if it could be achieved using Linq "_ You are already using LINQ

Comment: Looks very "linqish" to me :) You can, however, chain these lines together: `personList.Where(l => l.IsMarried == true).SelectMany(c => c.Children).Where(test => test.Greater5 == true).SelectMany(test => test.ListColor.Where(c => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Type)).Select(t => t.Type)).ToList();`

Comment: I agree with @OfirWinegarten and would add that calling ToList() repeatedly as you are doing can have a performance impact on the code so chaining can improve this.

Comment: Personally I like the way you do, its more readable for me. What you could improve is to add `var` and remove `.ToList()` in first 2 lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain `SelectMany` to flatten nested children.

```
List<string> wantedList = personList
    .Where(person => person.IsMarried)
    .SelectMany(person => person.Children
        .Where(child => child.Greater5)
        .SelectMany(child => child.ListColor
            .Where(color => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(color.Type))
            .Select(color => color.Type)))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You also could use query language if that looks "simpler" to you:

```
List<string> wantedList = (from person in personList where person.IsMarried
                           from child in person.Children where child.Greater5 
                           from color in child.ListColor where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(color.Type)
                           select color.Type).ToList();
```